# Spring: how to use resourceLoader to inject a file located on the machine but not in the classpath

Tags: spring

I want the spring application to be able to go into the localhost and load a given path into the resource loader so it can be read by the server. The code below is trying to access a file a valid .txt file on my computer stored on my desktop.

What follows is my resource-loader implementation.

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class CustomResourceLoader implements ResourceLoaderAware {
    @Autowired
    private ResourceLoader rsld;

    @Override
    public void setResourceLoader(ResourceLoader rsld) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      this.rs = rs;
    }
    public void showResource(String path) throws IOException{
        Resource resour = rsld.getResource("file:"+path);
        File fl = resour.getFile();
        System.out.println(fl.exists());
        System.out.println(fl.getAbsoluteFile());
        System.out.println(fl.getName());
    }

}
```

The output to calling the show resource method is as follows:

```
false
/Users/wes/Documents/workspace/rest-services-AM/{
    "/Users/wes/Desktop/wes.txt"}
wes.txt
```

I understand that this means that my resource is not returning an actual file so i can not use it. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As nobody seems to be aware of, I found out that it's just necessairy to use double slashes like:

```
@Value("\\\\MY-MACHINE\\thefile.txt")
private Resource file;
```

In some cases you may required a file: statement before, like: file:\\MY-MACHINE\thefile.txt"